# Disable Kafka connection in SpringBoot tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm working on a springboot project following a microservice architecture and I use Kafka as an event bus to exchange data between some of them. I also have Junit tests which test some part of my application which doesn't require the bus and others that require it by using an embedded Kafka broker.

The problem I have is when I launch all my tests, they take so much time and they fail because each of then is trying to connect to the embedded Kafka broker (*connection not available*) whereas they don't need Kafka bus in order to achieve their task.

Is it possible to disable the loading of Kafka components for these tests and only allow them for the ones that require it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually write my JUnit tester classes, that usually wont connect to KAFKA Brokers for each test.

1. Mocking the REST API, if your KAFKA Client (Producer/Consumer) integrated with a REST API

public class MyMockedRESTAPI {

```
public MyMockedRESTAPI() {
}

public APIResponseWrapper apiResponseWrapper(parameters..) throws RestClientException {
    if (throwException) {
        throw new RestClientException(....);
    }
    return new APIResponseWrapper();
}
```

}

2. A factory class to generate an incoming KAFKA Event and REST API request and response wrappers

public class mockFactory {

```
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

public static KAKFAEvent generateKAFKAEvent() {
    KAKFAEvent kafkaEvent = new KAKFAEvent();
    kafkaEvent.set...
    kafkaEvent.set...
    kafkaEvent.set...

    return KAKFAEvent;
}


public static ResponseEntity<APIResponse> createAPIResponse() {
    APIResponse response = new APIResponse();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

3. A Test Runner Class

   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

   public class KAFKAJUnitTest {

   Your assertion should be declared here

   }

You can also refer : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing

Answer (score 0):

a good practice would be to avoid sending messages to Kafka while testing code in your isolated microservice scope. but when you need to make an integration test ( many microservices in the same time ) sometimes you need to activate Kafka messages.

So my purpose is :

1- Activate/Deactivate loding Kafka configuration as required

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.kafka.consumer", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration {
...
}

@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.kafka.producer", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {
...
}
```

and then u will be able to activate/deactivate loading consumer and producer as you need...

Examples :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class)
public class MyMicroservice_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMicroservice_1.class, args);
    }
}
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(KafkaProducerConfiguration.class)
public class MyMicroservice_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMicroservice_2.class, args);
    }
}
```

or maybe a microservice that need both of configurations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = { KafkaProducerConfiguration.class, KafkaConsumerConfiguration.class })
public class MyMicroservice_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMicroservice_3.class, args);
    }
}
```

2 - You need also to make sending messages depending on the current spring profile. To do that u can override the send method of the Kafka template object:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.kafka.producer", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {
...

    @Resource
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory()) {

            @Override
            protected ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> doSend(ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord) {

                if (Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test")) {
                        return null;            
                }

                return super.doSend(producerRecord);
            }

        };
    }
    
        @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        ...

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }
    
}
```